# How to calculate distance using latitude and longitude?

Tags: c#, sql, latitude-longitude

I have table having latitude and longitude

---

```
     Lat            Longitude
```

---

```
40.8151 -73.0455    U   36103
40.8132 -73.0476    U   36103
```

So what i want is I am passing two Longitude and latitude from my page How can i find nearest place  using store procedure i don't have a much hand on it so i have to ask here

Tried using this one

```
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( @latitude ) ) * cos( radians( @longtitude ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( @latitude ) ) ) )
```

But i have to match it with the table values so how can i achieve this?

Comment: You might find this page useful: http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(6371 * acos(cos(radians('lat')) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians('long')) + sin(radians('lat')) * sin(radians(latitude)))) as distance,latitude,longitude, from your_table HAVING distance<=20  order by distance
```

You can use a query similar to shown above in your SQL where `'lat'` and `'long'` are the variable values that you are passing to search for. The `'longitude'` and `'latitude'` are column names from your table. And btw, this is called Haversine formula and the constant `6371` is used to get distance in KM, while `3959` is used to get distance in miles. You can use either of them as per your requirement.

Comment: @dholakiyaankit - **what** error is it giving you? Try to be specific in your feedback when people are trying to help you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever round requires two or three values

Comment: @dholakyaankit: I gave this query just as a piece of suggestion. You may need to make appropriate changes to it for it to run on your SQL server. This may require looking upto function syntax. However, the formula shall remain same.

Comment: Please note, this formula is valid for a **sphere**. In case you need a more precise calculation, you have to look for something else.

Comment: Still i don't feel that this answer is helpful for me sorry

Comment: This formula is buggy. I am using it for years and I discovered today it has a bug. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522005/select-points-from-map-database-according-to-radius and help me if you have any knowledge into this.

Comment: I checked the post. The concern is raised in cases where the matching point is at the center. I believe in such cases, we can check for absolute match of the coords instead of calculating the distance. However, that is just a suggestion; I haven't tested this personally, given that this post is years old now.