# find nearest location using SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find nearest location saved in my database table

```
nama_sekolah            latitude(lat)       longitude(lon)

SMA 1                   -6.811587           110.851419
SMA 2                   -6.804751           110.825048
SMA 3                   -6.804658           110.874171
SMA 4                   -6.787235           110.865934
SMA 5                   -6.743791           110.839555
SMA 6                   -6.833336           110.869366
SMA 7                   -6.805317           110.926164
```

i have tried with this code bellow, but with no one result 
nearestCat is checkbox and $terdekat is input text for distance in KiloMeters

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['nearestCat'])) {              
    $origLat = -6.811;
    $origLon = 110.851;
    $dist = $terdekat; // This is the maximum distance (in km) away from $origLat, $origLon in which to search
    $query = "SELECT*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($origLat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians($origLon) ) + sin( radians($origLat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < $dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";

    $no=1;
    while ($hasil = mysql_query($query)) { ?>
    <table border: 1px solid black; >
    <tr text-align:center>
       <th>No</th><th>NSS</th><th>Nama Sekolah</th><th>Jenis Sekolah</th><th>Akreditasi</th><th>Kecamatan</th><th>Alamat</th><th colspan="2">Aksi</th>
    </tr>

    <tr text-align='center'>
        <td align='center'><? echo "$no" ?></td>
        <td><? echo "$data[nss]"?></td>
        <td><? echo "$data[nama_sekolah]"?></td>
        <td><? echo "$data[jenis_sekolah]"?></td>
        <td><? echo "$data[akreditasi]"?></td>
        <td><? echo "$data[kecamatan]"?></td>
        <td><? echo "$data[alamat]"?></td>  
        <td><?php echo "<a href='detail.php?id=$data[id]'title='Detail'><u>Selengkapnya</u></a>" ?></td>
        <td><?php echo "<a href='map_besar.php?id=$data[id]'title='Peta'><u>Lihat Peta</u></a>" ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php $no++; }
    echo "</table>";
     }

    ?>
```

can anyone help me to fix my code above.. i'm newbie in php n mysql.. CMIIW
thanks for your help

Comment: What output you want? Does this code return any error?

Comment: table, that showing the result, it return with no error

Comment: what value you are passing to `$terdekat`. say pass value like `100` and check.

Comment: yeah, value that i pass in $terdekat is about 1-20 km.. and check it

Comment: there may be no matching records within given range even you canb refer this one.. visit [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084886/how-to-calculate-distance-using-latitude-and-longtitude)

Comment: remove `distance < $dist` condition and check that what distance value it returns. It must return more than 20km.

Comment: it still show with no one result

Comment: does this code `"SELECT*,` is right

Comment: use `where` conditions and make `distance` to subquery..

Comment: `SELECT*` should be `select *`

Comment: `echo $query;` and check the printed query and execute it in your database.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions in production code, ext/mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5, and will be removed in PHP7. Use the superior [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions/classes instead. Also see: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql query seems fine, but there is a problem with the way it is executed in php.

When you run the mysql_query you get a resource on success. You can then use this resource to fetch the data, so you would replace

```
while ($hasil = mysql_query($query)) {
```

With the following

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

The var `$row` will be an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row. So you would echo for example `$row['nama_sekolah']`

I'd also recommend you use mysqli since mysql functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: okay, i will be using mysqli latter, but now for temporary i work with php 5.2 .. hihih for my collage task..

Comment: i have try your advice but, it still not showing the data .. does there is some error with this code `$query ="SELECT*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($origLat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lon ) - radians($origLon) ) + sin( radians($origLat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < $dist ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";`

Comment: does `lat` and `lon`  that i take from database is true in writing `radian(lat)`  and `radian(lon)`??

Comment: Perhaps check your field names match the database table. I used the following in phpmyadmin successfully with test table `SELECT*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-6.811) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(110.851) ) + sin( radians(-6.811) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 100 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20`

Comment: there is some error with using  `mysql_fetch_assoc` and also i try with `mysql_fetch_array` too.. Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Comment: Is your db connection setup correctly? I'd suggest you run the query in phpmyadmin to test and get error message.

Comment: oh i found the problem,, the problem is i forget to define this `$dist = "$_POST[terdekat]"` . thanks for your help.. i appriciate it..